# How do I show number of results in my site's Google search result

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-search-api, search-engine-api

If a search result on Google links to a page that has a number of listings on it (see image) the result often shows the number of listings on that page.

[image]

This can be seen here https://goo.gl/ghl0gN

I cant find documentation from any of the search engines that shows how to do this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I believe this might be done in Google Webmaster Tools - you can use the Data Highlighter (in the Search Appearance section). Using the tool it will render a page of your choosing - a product listing page for example - and enable you to select areas to be included in search listings such as price, availability, product title etc. However, I don't recall seeing listing numbers in there so it might just be a case of Google (et al) including the rendered text in the search result and then putting it at the start of the description by default.